# EF Core 2.1 trying to include primary key field in INSERT query when adding to DbContext and saving

Tags: dbcontext, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

In an ASP .Net Core 2.1 Web API (with a MySQL database and using Pomelo), when I add a new entity to the database in one of my controller actions, if the entity that is received by the API from the consuming client has a value in the primary key, it appears as though EF Core is trying to add the primary key instead of allowing the database to give it a new value.

So... in the database, I have a table called `person` which has an integer field called `id` which is set to PRIMARY KEY and AUTO-INCREMENT.

**Model:**

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("person");

        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .HasColumnType("int(11)");

        entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasColumnName("name")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(45)");

        entity.Property(e => e.Surname)
            .HasColumnName("surname")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(45)");
    }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
// POST: api/Person
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPerson([FromBody]Person person)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    _context.Person.Add(person);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtAction("GetPerson", new { id = person.Id }, person);
}
```

If I don't specifically clear the Id of the person before trying to insert it into the database (i.e. `person.Id = null`) then I get an exception complaining about duplicate primary key. Is this normal EF Core behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why would your primary key allow null values?  Wouldn't you always want a value there?

Comment: Yes, this behavior is "by design". It is for allowing identity insert scenarios. EF6 works differently, which might be confusing if you are coming from EF6.

Comment: Hi Josh. It never used to allow nulls (i.e. it used to be a plain int, not an int?) but I modified it to allow nulls so that I can set it to null just before saving it to the database, so that it allows the database to assign it a number instead of trying to use the one it already had.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, yes, you are doing something wrong. For a whole host of reasons, you should never ever save an instance created from user input (i.e. the `Person` instance being passed into your action and created from the request body of the post) directly to your database. One such reason is that it causes havoc with ORMs like EF, which employ entity tracking to optimize queries.

Simply, this `Person` instance here is untracked - EF knows nothing about it. You then use `Add` to add it to your context, which signals EF to start tracking it as a new thing. When you later save, EF, then dutifully issues an insert statement, but since an id is included in that insert, you get a primary key conflict. What you wanted instead was for EF to do an update, but it doesn't know it should.

There's ways you can technically fix this. For example, you could use `Attach` rather than `Add`. That merely blindly tells EF that this is something it should track, without necessarily communicating that it should do anything with it. If you make any modifications to this instance after it is tracked, EF will change its change to "modified" and you'll end up with an update statement being issued when you save. However, if you're *not* making any changes, but just saving it directly, you'll also need to explicitly set it's state to "modified" or EF will essentially do nothing. The nice thing is that if you change the state on an untracked entity, then EF automatically attaches it to track said state, so you you don't need to do `Attach` manually. Long and short, you can clear the exception merely by replacing your `Add` line with:

```
_context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

However, that then will cause a problem if you try to add a new person entirely. A bigger issue you have here is that you have one action doing double duty. According to REST, a POST is not replayable and should only be made to resources which or idempotent. Put more simply, you POST only to a resource like `/api/person` (rather than something like `/api/person/1` and every time you do so *a new person should be created*. For an update, you should make a request to that actual resource, i.e `/api/person/1` and the HTTP verb should be PUT, instead. The same PUT request to the same resource will always have the same result, which is the case for an update to a particular resource.

Theory aside, the simple point is that you should have two actions:

```
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPerson([FromBody]Person person)

[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePerson(int id, [FromBody]Person person)
```

Finally, even with all this, saving the person param directly puts too much trust in the user, when doing an update. There might be any number of properties an end-user should not be able to modify with an update (such as something like a "created" date, for example), but they can when you do this. In some ways worse, even if the user is not being malicious, you're still relying on them to post *all* the data for that entity. For example, if you did have a created date property, but the user doesn't post that with their update (honestly, why *would* you post a created date along with a request to update a resource), then it will have the effect of clearing that property out. If there's a default, it will be set back to that, and if not, you may actually get an exception on saving, if the column is NOT NULL.

Long and short, it's not a good idea. Instead, use a view model, DTO, or similar. That class should contain only properties you want to allow a user to modify or even to affect on create in the first place. Then, for the case of an update, you pull the resource fresh from the database, and map over the values from your param instance onto that. Finally, you save the version from the database back to the database. This ensures 1) the user cannot modify anything you do not explicitly allow, 2) the user only needs to post things they actually care about modifying, and 3) the entity will be properly tracked and EF will issue an update statement correctly on save.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed reply Chris. I see now where I went wrong. P.s. I do have a separate action for updating the Person as in your example (i.e. for a PUT) - I just didn't include it in my post as that was working fine :) Also I completely agree with you in using a DTO instead of the database model directly. I will let you know shortly if it worked...

Comment: Sorry, after re-reading your post, I'm not 100% sure why you're saying "What you wanted instead was for EF to do an update". This is a brand new Person entity that needs to be added to the database. So this is executing in a POST controller action, and receiving the new person object in the body of the post.

Comment: I could receive a DTO in the controller action, as you suggested, instead of the Person object. This DTO could exclude the ID field. But I think I would still need to map the DTO to the Person object before I can add it to the DbContext?

I guess as long as I keep the Id field in the Person class a nullable int, then it would be fine? I'm not sure I like the Id field being declared as a nullable int though (like I unfortunately had to do in my case) as in the database, it does not allow nulls...